# Convert hash keys to lowercase -- Ruby Beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My table field names are lowercase and the field names I get from CSV files are camelcase. Is there anyway I can convert the keys of an array of hashes to lowercase?

Here is the code I have right now:

```
    CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
      Users.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
```

This is failing because the keys are camel case (I've verified this by manually editing the file to make the header row all lowercase).

PS. Also I would love to know why the hell rails takes table field names' case sensitivity into play to begin with?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
  new_hash = {}
  row.to_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
   new_hash.merge!({k.downcase => v}) 
  end

  Users.create!(new_hash)
end
```

I had no time to test it but, you can take idea of it.
 Hope it will help

Comment: That works! But I'm also curious as to why the heck rails would enforce case here (my file system isn't case sensitive so that is not the issue).

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not unserstand what do you mean saying: rails takes table field names' case sensitivity into play to begin with? :) (Maybe this is my bad english knowledge :) )

Comment: Meaning why does rails require case of field names in table to match the keys in the hash during insertion

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Your DB is (probably) case-sensitive, and Rails just passes the names through.

Answer (score 26):

You can just use the header_converters option with CSV:

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true, :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.try(:downcase) }) do |row|
  Users.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

Important to put the .try in there since an empty header will throw an exception. Much better (and faster) than doing this on every row.

Answer (score 10):

You can simple do

```
hash.transform_keys(&:downcase)
```

to change hash keys to lowercase, or you can also transform hash values to lowercase or upper case as per your requirement.

`hash.transform_values(&:downcase)` or `hash.transform_values(&:upcase)`

```
hash = {:A=>"b", :C=>"d", :E=>"f"}
hash.transform_keys(&:downcase)
=> {:a=>"b", :c=>"d", :e=>"f"}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since this was tagged with Rails.

With ActiveSupport starting vom version 3.0 you can use a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

That will allow lower/uppercase/symbol writing to access the keys or your Hash.

```
my_hash = { "camelCase": "some value" }
my_hash.with_indifferent_access[:camelcase] # 'some value'
my_hash.with_indifferent_access['camelcase'] # 'some value'
my_hash.with_indifferent_access['camelCase'] # 'some value'
my_hash.with_indifferent_access['CAMELCASE'] # 'some value'
```

ActiveSupport 4.0.2 also introduced this:

```
my_hash.deep_transform_keys!(&:downcase)
# or if your hash isn't nested:
my_hash.transform_keys!(&:downcase)
```

Comment: `with_indifferent_access` is supporting string-or-symbol, but is *not case insensitive* for me.  ActiveSupport 5.0.4.

Comment: Same as Justin Maxwell here.  I used an alternative instead.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby 1.9 provides quite a nice way to achieve this, using each_with_object to avoiding initialising a temporary variable.

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
  new_hash = row.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
    h[k.downcase] = v
  end

  Users.create!(new_hash)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I find this approach more elegant:

```
hash_with_camelcase_keys.to_a.map { |pair| [pair.first.downcase, pair.last] }.to_h
```

Comment: `to_a.map { |key, value| [key.upcase.to_s, value] }.to_h` looks cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the hash directly, more efficient than merge! because you're not creating a new hash for every pair.

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
  new_hash = {}
  row.to_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
   new_hash[k.downcase] = v 
  end

  Users.create!(new_hash)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that this solution is significantly faster and a bit more "Rubyish".

```
CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
  new_hash = Hash[row.to_hash.map { |k, v| [k.downcase, v] }]
  Users.create!(new_hash)
end
```

Comment: Not sure it is more rubyish - it uses a class or module method which even uses a method ending in !

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using `underscore` instead of `downcase` because this would also transform the `CamelCase` to `camel_case` notation, which is more Rubylike.

**My personal preferences goes to using `deep_transform_keys`:** `hash.deep_transform_keys{|key| key.underscore.to_sym }`

*As `transform_keys` do not traverse the whole hash.*